# How to add extra major grid lines in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have the following dataset:

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -2486022 ymin: -1025641 xmax: 954903.6 ymax: 2252011
CRS:            EPSG:32119
          VAR     residual                       geometry
1 total_resid  0.052358204 MULTIPOLYGON (((-260020.6 -...
2 total_resid  0.051623652 MULTIPOLYGON (((904798.7 65...
3 total_resid -1.780438621 MULTIPOLYGON (((772940.8 57...
4 total_resid -0.012465629 MULTIPOLYGON (((429779.8 -9...
5 total_resid -0.009121893 MULTIPOLYGON (((7030.591 15...
6 total_resid  0.097626207 MULTIPOLYGON (((-2401716 17...
```

If I put it here with `dput` it is too long to put it here. My question, I want to plot this data on a grid with major grid lines every degree. My code looks like this:

```
facet_sources_State_Residuals = ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sources_State_Residuals, aes(fill=residual)) + 
  facet_wrap(~VAR, ncol=3, nrow=1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white")) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='blue', mid='white', high='red', midpoint=0, limits=c(-0.25,0.25), oob=squish) + 
  geom_sf(data = usbigcities, color = 'black') + labs(fill="USGS-PCRGLOB [m3/m2/year]")
```

And the plot looks like this:
[image: plot]

But what I want is to have a spacing of 1 degree between the gridlines instead of the 10 degrees it is now. I already tried to use `breaks` but that did not work.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`breaks` works in `scale_*_continuous` to adjust the major gridlines:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sf")
library("raster")

us <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "USA", level = 1) %>%
  st_as_sf %>%
  st_transform(32119) 
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = us) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-130, -70, 5)) +
  facet_wrap(~GID_0)
```

[image: map]

Did you specify negative values for `breaks`?

Comment: that was indeed the case! Do you also know how to reduce the axis ticks? So that you can see the lines but only have steps of 10 as labels?

Comment: This usually accomplished using `minor_breaks`, but doesn't not work here. As workaround you could use the `labels` argument with empty strings at some positions.

Comment: That means that I have to use use 9 empty strings in every 10 strings in a sequence of -130 to -70. Isn't that a bit arbitrary?

Comment: If I put it there like ```scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-130, -60, 1), labels= c('-130','','','','','','','','','','-120','','','','','','','','','','-110','','','','','','','','','','-100','','','','','','','','','','-90','','','','','','','','','','-80','','','','','','','','','','-70','','','','','','','','','','-60'))``` Then I get the error ''breaks and labels are different lengths''. I counted and checked everything twice, but I don't see why they are not the same length. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe it's cleaner/simpler to add the graticules (on a finer level) manually before plotting the map, e.g. `ggplot() + geom_sf(data = st_graticule(us, lon = seq(-130, -70, 1)), colour="white") + geom_sf(data = us) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-130, -70, 5))`